# present perfect combined with simple present and present continuous

Tags: present-tense

Suppose that you are talking to your friends about some of the customer reviews regarding their online shopping experiences. This is what you would say to them.

(ex) I **have just read** some customer reviews regarding their online shopping experiences with ABC Store. They **are complaining** about a high import duty they **need** to pay when they **receive** their orders.

Some of my non-native English speaking friends think my use of the mixed present tenses is okay because it carries a sense that the customers' complaints are ongoing. However, others think I should use the past tense.

I think I can use different present tenses in this context. Please give me your opinion.

Comment: the example looks correct

Comment: *I have just read some customer reviews regarding [] online shopping experiences with ABC store. **Customers** are complaining...* Otherwise, ***their*** makes it seem as if it's the customer reviews that are having experiences, not the customers.